# SSRS sorting for String+Numeric values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a column(specifically, a row group) in SSRS R3 2012 with values like Adam 2, Adam 3, Adam 11, Adam 12, John A, John B, Stuart 1, Stuart 2, Stuart 11.

When I sort it A to Z in SSRS, it sorts it like

```
Adam 11
Adam 12
Adam 2
Adam 3
John A
John B
Stuart 1
Stuart 11
Stuart 2
```

How do I sort it so that it is in the order like

```
Adam 2
Adam 3
Adam 11
Adam 12
John A
John B
Stuart 1
Stuart 2
Stuart 11
```

Comment: Can you change the process that appends the numbers the names?

Comment: How will appending the string to number help?

Comment: Because if you were to have `Adam 001`, `Adam 002` and `Adam 010` they would sort correctly without additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions in your sort to accomplish this. The expressions below assume your string value always has a space before the extra data. Create 2 sorts on the row group.

For the first sort use an expression to get the first part of the string which is the name. `Left(Fields!Value.Value, InStrRev(Fields!Value.Value, " "))`.

For the second sort use an expression to get the data after the name.

```
=CInt(IIF(
    IsNumeric(Right(Fields!ColumnName.Value, Len(Fields!ColumnName.Value) - InStrRev(Fields!ColumnName.Value, " "))), 
    Right(Fields!ColumnName.Value, Len(Fields!ColumnName.Value) - InStrRev(Fields!ColumnName.Value, " ")), 
    0
))
```

Comment: Actually, the data is not that uniform. I have values such as "Bob Bryan AC", "William Jr 01" etc. As you said, this solutions works perfectly for values like "Adam 01" "Adam 11" etc. Thank you for the response btw :) Is there a way to modify the data to make this sorting easier?

Comment: If you always have a space at the end before the extra data you can use InStrRev instead of InStr. Updated my answer with new code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can edit the daatset Query...
I have written a couple of functions for this type of thing.

**fn.ConvertToValue()** this converts string to values by stripping out non-numeric stuff, if also handles strings that have a "%" symbol and coverts those to fractional percentages. So, fn.ConvertToValue('Adam Bob 123') will return 123.

Conversley
**fn.StripToAlpha(()** Returns the non-numeric part only so fn.StripToAlpha('Adma Bob 123') will return 'Adam Bob'

Once you have these functions created you can simply change your SQL to something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
    ORDER BY fn.StripToAlpha(myColumn), fn.ConvertToValue(myColumn)
```

Here is the code for the functions. You might want to change the Schema name from 'fn' .

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[ConvertToValue]
    (@inputString nvarchar(4000))  
RETURNS Float
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @ReturnVal Float
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    IF @inputString IS NULL
        BEGIN
            Return NULL
        END

    IF @Len = 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@inputString))) = 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal=0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            WHILE @Counter<=@Len
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter = @Counter +1

                SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

                IF(@ascii BETWEEN 48 AND 57) OR (@ascii IN (46,37)) 
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
                END
            END

            if RIGHT(@strReturnVal,1)='%'
                BEGIN
                    SET @strReturnVal = LEFT(@strReturnVal,len(@strReturnVal)-1)
                    SET @strReturnVal = CAST((CAST(@strReturnVal AS FLOAT)/100) AS nvarchar(4000))
                END

            SET @ReturnVal = ISNULL(@strReturnVal,0)
        END

    RETURN @ReturnVal


END
```

and

```
CREATE   FUNCTION fn.StripToAlpha
(@inputString nvarchar(4000))  
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Counter as int
    DECLARE @strReturnVal varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @Len as int
    DECLARE @ASCII as int

    SET @Counter=0  
    SET @Len=LEN(@inputString)

    SET @strReturnVal = ''

    WHILE @Counter<=@Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1

        SET @ascii= ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))

        IF(@ascii BETWEEN 65 AND 90) OR (@ascii BETWEEN 97 AND 122) 
        BEGIN
            SET @strReturnVal = @strReturnVal + (SUBSTRING(@inputString,@counter,1))
        END
    END

    RETURN @strReturnVal

END
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. Seems a tad complicated for a simple issue though :)

Comment: It might seem a lot of work but once the functions are in place, it makes stuff like this easy. There are other, in-line ways to do this but it just means more code each time. I always think it's better to solve a problem once and reuse it.